# Sort bibliography by type

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

In my bibliography I want to sort by type, for example first all books and then all interviews, webpages, etc. I am using natbib, is it possible to do that? I cannot find any clues where ever I look...

Comment: With `biblatex` this would be easy. Is switching to `biblatex` an option for you?

Comment: Yes, at least I have to find a solution so if it is easier with biblatex I can use that instead. What do I need to include to make it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `biblatex` you can comfortably divide the references with `\printbibliography[type=book]`. The main difference is, that you should now use `biber` instead of `bibtex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[    
    style=authoryear,   
    natbib=true,        
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{blub,
    year={1992},
    booktitle={Booktitle},
    volume={59},
    editor={Editor, A. and Editor, B. and Editor, C.},
    title="{Title}",
    publisher={Springer, New York},
    author={Author, A. and Author, B. and Author, C. and Author, D. and Author, E.},
}

@article{test,
    year={1992},
    title={article},
    author={Author, A. and Author, B. and Author, C. and Author, D. and Author, E.},
}
\end{filecontents}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

    \printbibliography[title=Books, type=book]

    \printbibliography[title=Journal Articles, type=article]


\end{document}
```

[image]